# Postgresql: avoid referencing schema in trigger function

Tags: postgresql, schema, psql, pg-dump

I have written function that I registered in a trigger that ensure referential consistency in non-normalized data (like we store agency_id + branch_id and I ensure that a referenced branch is inside a reference agency).

The function has some selects:

```
SELECT b.agency_id INTO agency_id FROM branch AS b WHERE b.id = NEW.branch_id;
IF NEW.agency_id <> agency_id THEN
  RAISE EXCEPTION 'privilege.agency_id (%) mismatches privilege.branch_id => agency.id (%)', NEW.agency_id, agency_id;
END IF;
```

All worked fine for several years until I run `pg_dump`. On import by `psql ... -f dump/dict-local.sql` I see errors:

```
ERROR:  42P01: relation "branch" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT b.agency_id                FROM branch AS b WHERE b.i...
                                               ^
QUERY:  SELECT b.agency_id                FROM branch AS b WHERE b.id = NEW.branch_id
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function SCHEMA.privilege_orgunit_ck() line 8 at SQL statement
```

After I added schema prefix: `SCHEMA.branch` import started to work. **I don't like to add schema prefix to tables referenced in the function. What can I do to avoid the error?**

Is it related to `search_path`? I seee in the very beginning of `pg_dump` output:

```
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
```

**UPDATE** There is [TG_TABLE_SCHEMA](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) mentioned in the docs. I'm not sure how to use it, using it as prefix `TG_TABLE_SCHEMA.branch` produces the same error:

```
psql:dump/dict-local.sql:4368: ERROR:  42P01: relation "tg_table_schema.branch" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT b.agency_id                FROM TG_TABLE_SCHEMA.branc...
```

If I need to rewrite select into:

```
EXECUTE format('SELECT ... INTO ... FROM %I.branch', TG_TABLE_SCHEMA);
```

it looks awful...

Comment: `I don't like to add schema prefix to tables referenced in the function.` Why? It's typically the cleanest, safest, fastest solution. `After I added schema prefix: SCHEMA.branch import started to work.` You mean the restore went through? Or did you see errors in operation? Also, please *always* declare your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I come up with:

```
PERFORM set_config('search_path', TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, true);
```

The last argument `true` ensures a change is only for the current transaction:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-admin.html

> If `is_local` is `true`, the new value will only apply to the current transaction. If you want the new value to apply for the current session, use `false` instead.

I don't know the scope trigger executes, so I'm not sure in the solution.

Comment: As your quote says: this changes the `search_path` for the scope of the whole transaction. Since you `don't know the scope trigger executes` and you `don't like to add schema prefix to tables`, this looks like a loaded footgun to me. Changing the `search_path` dynamically is generally expensive as it causes a context switch and voids all saved query plans. I would rather not go there. If you must, then save the current `search_path` and restore it at the end of the trigger function.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I ended up with embedding schema name. It is unfortunate that `pg_dump` clears `search_path`. Actually I think I can pre-process `pg_dump` output removing a line that clears 'search_path'. I agree that altering `search_path` is expensive. It is the cleanest solution as problem only with that utility which I used once a year.